# Powershell script to clear text after localhost line and add static hostname and current ip address to the file

Tags: windows, powershell, hosts-file

Need to clear all text after the line 127.0.0.1 localhost host file in PowerShell. last line is the localhost entry in the host file after this line I would like to delete all text lines is it possible. Below is the code.

```powershell
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted 

$ip = get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration|Where {$_.Ipaddress.length -gt 1} 

$ip.ipaddress[0]
$hst = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$hostfile = Get-Content "$($env:windir)\system32\Drivers\etc\hosts"
if ($hostfile -notcontains "127.0.0.2 hostname1" -and 
    (-not($hostfile -like "$($ip.ipaddress[0]) $hst"))) {
    Add-Content -Encoding UTF8 "$($env:windir)\system32\Drivers\etc\hosts" "$($ip.ipaddress[0]) $hst" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This scripts deletes anything after `127.0.0.1 localhost` and saves it back to the file. In case your conditions resolve to be true, the new entry is injected before the file is being written back to disk.

**The code:**

```powershell
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted 

$ipAdresses = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object {$_.IPAddress.length -gt 0} | Select-Object -Property 'IPAddress' -First 1

$ip = $ipAdresses.IPAddress[0]
$hst = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$hostFilePath = "$($env:windir)\system32\Drivers\etc\hosts"
$hostfile = Get-Content -Path $hostFilePath
$newHostFileEntry = "{0} {1}" -f $ip, $hst

# Delete all text after what is defined as $matchString
$lastIndexOfNewArray = 0
$matchString = '127.0.0.1\s+localhost'

for ($index = 0; $index -lt $hostfile.Count; $index++) {
    if ($hostfile[$index] -match $matchString) {
        $lastIndexOfNewArray = $index
        break
    }
}
$newHostFileContent = $Hostfile[0..$lastIndexOfNewArray]

# Adds entry for local IP address if conditions resolve to $true
if ($newHostFileContent -notcontains "127.0.0.2 hostname1" -and 
    (-not($newHostFileContent -like $newHostFileEntry))) {
        $newHostFileContent = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList(,$newHostFileContent)
        $newHostFileContent.Add($newHostFileEntry) > $null
}

Out-File -Encoding UTF8 -FilePath $hostFilePath -InputObject $newHostFileContent -Append:$false -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Wow Thank you its working awesome when run within powershell editor but not from right click " Run with Powershell " am i doing something wrong. Thank you again.

Comment: Is there any kind of error message? Else, you might open a PowerShell and start the script file from there to see what has possibly gone wrong.

Comment: There is error when i do it right click Run with powershell it flashes in red for a millisecond on screen which i could not record. But the script executes without error within Powershell editor and appends the host file without issues. Let me know if we can capture the error in log file i am new to powershell Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ok then try to open a PowerShell first and start the script file from within. That should keep the PowerShell window open and you can tell about the error.

Comment: This is the error i am getting if i execute the file within powershell

Comment: D:\UpdateHosstfileip.ps1 : The term 'D:\UpdateHosstfileip.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
+ D:\UpdateHosstfileip.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\UpdateHosstfileip.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: I feel sorry to ask, but is the typo `UpdateHosstfileip.ps1` intended? The error usually points out, that the file could not be found.

Comment: i am sorry this is a typo i could execute the command without error from powershell command prompt. But i am still getting error from right click "Run with powershell" context menu. Thanks

Comment: Maybe [starting a PowerShell from within a PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1340661/8179604) with the `-noexit` option can bring up the error. Else, you should make sure your execution policy allows running Scripts. Therefore check `Get-ExecutionPolicy` and use `Set-ExecutionPolicy` as explained by [Microsofts online help for Set-ExecutionPolicy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-6)